# Realizar backup automático usando Docker

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

Minha aplicação está composta de Frontend (Vue.js) + Backend (Node.js com banco postgresql), antes de jogar em produção eu dockerizei usando docker e docker-compose.

Segue abaixo como está o arquivo docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: <POSTGRES_PASSWORD>
      POSTGRES_USER: <POSTGRES_USER>
      POSTGRES_DB: <POSTGRES_DB>
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: db

  backend:
    image: backend
    command: sh -c "npm install -g knex && knex migrate:latest && npm start"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    ports:  
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: backend

  frontend:
    image: frontend
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    container_name: frontend
```

Basicamente tenho 3 containers que se comunicam. No sistema, o backup do banco de dados acontece de 2 formas:

1. Automaticamente de 7 em 7 dias;
2. O usuário administrador tem acesso a uma tela no frontend que permite realizar um backup manualmente.

Esse segundo método funciona da seguinte forma, no backend tem uma rota `/backup` que executa uma função com um comando cmd na máquina, usando a ferramenta 'pg_dump' do postgresql. Aqui está essa função (fica no backend):

```
const {
   exec
} = require('child_process');    

function backup() {
    execute(`pg_dump -U ${username} -d ${database} -f ${fileName} -F t`,).then(async () => {
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
 
backup();
```

Até ai tudo bem, tudo funciona perfeitamente enquanto a aplicação não está dockerizada. Porém quando eu dockerizo e tento fazer um backup acontece o seguinte error:

```
/bin/sh: pg_dump: not found
```

Isso acontece pois no container do backend, não é o container do bd, logo não tem o driver do Postgresql nem o banco de dados.

Existe alguma forma de acessar o container db pelo container backend e executar o comando `pg_dump`?